# C# XmlReader reads XML wrong and different based on how I invoke the reader's methods

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xmlreader

So my current understanding of how the C# `XmlReader` works is that it takes a given XML File and reads it node-by-node when I wrap it in a following construct:

```
using System.Xml;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
...
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.IgnoreComments = true;
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path, settings))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // All reader methods I call here will reference the current node
        // until I move the pointer to some further node by calling methods like
        // reader.Read(), reader.MoveToContent(), reader.MoveToElement() etc
    }
}
```

Why will the following two snippets (within the above construct) produce two very different results, even though they both call the same methods?

[I used this example file for testing.](https://pastebin.com/RsdVb4eM)

```
Debug.WriteLine(new string(' ', reader.Depth * 2) + "<" + reader.NodeType.ToString() + "|" + reader.Name + ">" + reader.ReadString() + "</>");
```

(Snippet 1)
vs
(Snippet 2)

```
string xmlcontent = reader.ReadString();
string xmlname = reader.Name.ToString();
string xmltype = reader.NodeType.ToString();
int xmldepth = reader.Depth;
Debug.WriteLine(new string(' ', xmldepth * 2) + "<" + xmltype + "|" + xmlname + ">" + xmlcontent + "</>");
```

Output of Snippet 1:

```
<XmlDeclaration|xml></>
<Element|rss></>
    <Element|head></>
        <Text|>Test Xml File</>
      <Element|description>This will test my xml reader</>
    <EndElement|head></>
    <Element|body></>
        <Element|g:id>1QBX23</>
        <Element|g:title>Example Title</>
        <Element|g:description>Example Description</>
      <EndElement|item></>
      <Element|item></>
          <Text|>2QXB32</>
        <Element|g:title>Example Title</>
        <Element|g:description>Example Description</>
      <EndElement|item></>
    <EndElement|body></>
  <EndElement|xml></>
<EndElement|rss></>
```

Yes, this is formatted as it was in my output window. As to be seen it skipped certain elements and outputted a wrong depth for a few others. Therefore, the NodeTypes are correct, unlike Snippet Number 2, which outputs:

```
<XmlDeclaration|xml></>
  <Element|xml></>
      <Element|title></>
      <EndElement|title>Test Xml File</>
      <EndElement|description>This will test my xml reader</>
    <EndElement|head></>
      <Element|item></>
        <EndElement|g:id>1QBX23</>
        <EndElement|g:title>Example Title</>
        <EndElement|g:description>Example Description</>
      <EndElement|item></>
        <Element|g:id></>
        <EndElement|g:id>2QXB32</>
        <EndElement|g:title>Example Title</>
        <EndElement|g:description>Example Description</>
      <EndElement|item></>
    <EndElement|body></>
  <EndElement|xml></>
<EndElement|rss></>
```

Once again, the depth is messed up, but it's not as critical as with Snippet Number 1. It also skipped some elements and assigned wrong NodeTypes.

Why can't it output the expected result? And why do these two snippets produce two totally different outputs with different depths, NodeTypes and skipped nodes?
I'd appreciate any help on this. I searched a lot for any answers on this but it seems like I'm the only one experiencing these issues. I'm using the .NET Framework 4.6.2 with Asp.net Web Forms in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Order matters because ReadString is going to advance the current position. However, the docs suggest not to use that method anyway.

Comment: @DaveM I know that the docs suggest using `ReadContentAsString()` or `ReadElementContentAsString()`, but at the moment I'd like to iterate over all nodes and both of those methods throw an error when they encounter a node which doesn't have any content. Why does ReadString() advance the position? Are there any alternatives I could use?

Comment: XmlReader is the “hard way” to parse xml in .net. But it is potentially much more efficient. It’s essentially stream-based so you can read/parse very large xml documents without having them entirely in memory. To make that work, many of the read operations advance the position (because the underlying stream has to be advanced, and “going back” is not easy or possible depending on the type of stream).

Comment: If you don’t have high performance requirements and are not trying to parse huge xml files, I’d suggest using XmlDocument instead.

Comment: If you know the xml format in advance, using the XmlSerializer (or equivalent) is even easier.

Comment: @DaveM for my task, using an XMLReader is essential because of performance reasons (I'm looking at XML files which are multiple gigabytes in size). My goal is to get all "column" names from the XML file (as if it would be an xlsx file). It would be important for me to know how I can iterate over these xml files the "correct" way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are using a method [`XmlReader.ReadString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readstring?view=netframework-4.8) **that is deprecated**:

> **XmlReader.ReadString Method**
>
> ... reads the contents of an element or text node as a string. However, we recommend that you use the [`ReadElementContentAsString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasstring?view=netframework-4.8) method instead, because it provides a more straightforward way to handle this operation.

However, beyond warning us off the method, the documentation doesn't precisely specify what it actually does.  To determine that, we need to go to the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,e6438794bbfe34cf):

```
public virtual  string  ReadString() {
    if (this.ReadState != ReadState.Interactive) {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    this.MoveToElement();
    if (this.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
        if (this.IsEmptyElement) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else if (!this.Read()) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString(Res.Xml_InvalidOperation));
        }
        if (this.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    string result = string.Empty;
    while (IsTextualNode(this.NodeType)) {
        result += this.Value;
        if (!this.Read()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This method does the following:

1. If the current node is an empty element node, return an empty string.
2. If the current node is an element that is not empty, *advance the reader*.

   If the now-current node is the end of the element, return an empty string.
3. While the current node is a text node, add the text to a string and *advance the reader*.  As soon as the current node is not a text node, return the accumulated string.

Thus we can see that this method *is designed to advance the reader*.  We can also see that, given mixed-content XML like `<head>text <b>BOLD</b> more text</head>`, `ReadString()` will only partially read the `<head>` element, leaving the reader positioned on `<b>`.  This oddity is likely why Microsoft deprecated the method.

We can also see why your two snippets function differently.  In the first, you get `reader.Depth` and `reader.NodeType` before calling `ReadString()` and advancing the reader.  In the second you get these properties after advancing the reader.

Since your intent is to iterate through the nodes and get the value of each, rather than `ReadString()` or `ReadElementContentAsString()` you should just use [`XmlReader.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.value?view=netframework-4.8):

> gets the text value of the current node.

Thus your corrected code should look like:

```
 string xmlcontent = reader.Value;
 string xmlname = reader.Name.ToString();
 string xmltype = reader.NodeType.ToString();
 int xmldepth = reader.Depth;
 Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', xmldepth * 2) + "<" + xmltype + "|" + xmlname + ">" + xmlcontent + "</>");
```

`XmlReader` is tricky to work with.  You always need to check the documentation to determine exactly where a given method positions the reader.  For instance, [`XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasstring?view=netframework-4.8) moves the reader *past* the end of the element, whereas [`XmlReader.ReadSubtree()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree?view=netframework-4.8) moves the reader *to* the end of the element.  But as a general rule any method named `Read` is going to advance the reader, so you need to be careful using a `Read` method inside an outer `while (reader.Read())` loop.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H7FdWh).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ll be testing your answer at work tomorrow. This does seem like a logical conclusion. +1

Comment: As a side note, how could I modify the fixed snippet to read an elements text content (if it has only a text node in it) while processing the element itself in the loop?

Comment: @SearchingSolutions - you can't really since `XmlReader` is forward-only.  The problem is as mentioned before that the element might have [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-mixed-content) such as `<body>text <b>BOLD</b> more text</body>`.  What you can could do is to defer emitting an element node and start reading its children.  If only text is encountered, accumulate it; if something else is encountered, emit the deferred node + the accumulated text.

Comment: If you know in advance the XML schema you have lots more options.

Comment: I’ve found a solution which works fine, sadly I can’t be sure what scheme the input file will have. Thanks for taking your time anyway!